# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0

Tags: python, pip, torchvision

When I try to install torchvision using the below command

```
pip install torchvision
```

I am getting the following error in the command-line tool. It would be great if someone could shoot a suggestion. I could not find where the issue is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a seperate [conda environment](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with `conda create --name myenv`

Activate this environment conda `activate myenv` and than install pytorch in it.

The [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/) gives you the right commands for your setup

Besides you can check which python you are currently using by `which python`.